# Recover a linux raid array after running "mdadm --create"?

Tags: linux, raid, centos7, mdadm

So I did something stupid and I'm wondering if I have any options.

I lost my OS drive (centos 7) but was able to keep my 4x 3tb raid drives.  So I reinstalled centos on another drive and tried to rebuild the array by running this command:

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
```

I think I was reading some documentation too fast and thought this implied that it would recreate the array for me.

I waited 2 full days and eventually mdstat looks clean:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid5 sdd1[2] sde1[4] sdc1[1] sdb1[0]
      8790398976 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

So obviously when I try to mount that, it appears to be missing a filesystem:

```
# mount /dev/md0 /opt/repository/
mount: /dev/md0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: unknown filesystem type '(null)'
```

Does anybody have any ideas for me or am I just stuck?  I get the feeling that after waiting for two days, it was doing some writing over my old data.

Comment: Gratulation you created and synced a fresh raid. i dont belive that you data will be still usable or present. restore them from backup